# recover vscode settings, vscode wont start after force ending update

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

VS Code has been trying to update for a few days now. It opens the `innoupdater`, but the updater never works.

Today I force stopped the updater from task manager and now my VS Code is gone (The VS Code icon is gone). It's showing the below error every time I try starting it.

```
windows cannot access the specified path you may not have permission
```

The `innoupdater` is also not working anymore, even if I reinstall. I am not sure How I can get my setting back.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to format your questions a bit so that they are readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely reinstall vscode. Settings preserved even after uninstall in `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`.

Also, you can use vscode built-in sync services or [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync)